# Eclipse importing a project failing

Tags: eclipse

I have created a project on a "Main" workspace. i have closed that project from that workspace, and tried to open the same project on another workspace "Learning". but when ever i tries to create this project i get an error that " overlaps the location of another project: ".

how to fix this.

Comment: Could you add the following information to your question: The exact layout of your workspaces and projects in your file system; the steps you have done to create the project; the distro you are using (Eclipse version); the additional plugins you have added?

Answer (score 0):

It general, it is not a good idea to share projects between workspaces on a file-system  basis. It works well if you share projects through a version control system, and create a checkout for both workspaces, but sharing the same files could cause troubles in the long run, as the builders in the different workspace might have been configured differently, thus moving the project into an inconsistent state.